# paho.mqtt.c message loss in a request/reply server

Tags: c, pthreads, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm testing a simple MQTT client-server model where a client is repeatedly sending requests to a server and awaits replies to each request. The flow is like this:

- Client subscribes to topic 'server/client' with QoS 1
- Server subscribes to topic 'client/server' with Qos 1
- Client sends 1000 messages to server, on message delivery, client increments its messagesOut counter by 1.
- Server receives a new message and invoke a registered callback. In the callback, the server sends a simple message to 'server/client'. On message delivery, the server increments its messagesOut counter.
- On new messages to topic 'server/client', the client will increment its messagesIn counter by 1.
- Both server and client will stop when client's messagesIn and server's messagesOut are 1000.

With QoS level 1, I expect the server to fully receives 1000 messages sent from the client, and sends 1000 replies back. However, my program is always stuck when the server has received and sent out about 200-300 messages. When I comment out the call to `MQTTAsync_sendMessage()`, the server can receive all 1000 messages. I suspect some kind of race condition or threads limit is causing this, but I'm not too sure.

The callback for new messages in the server looks like this:

```c
#define TOPIC_IN   "client/server"
#define TOPIC_OUT  "server/client"
#define PAYLOAD    "hello client\n"

unsigned long long messagesIn = 0, messagesOut = 0;

int on_message_arrival (void *context, char *topic_name, 
                        int topic_length, MQTTAsync_message *message) {
    if (!strcmp(topic_name, TOPIC_IN)) {
        MQTTAsync_freeMessage(&message);
        MQTTAsync_free(topic_name);

        messagesIn++;

        MQTTAsync_message pub_message = MQTTAsync_message_initializer;
        MQTTAsync_responseOptions opts = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;

        pub_message.payload = PAYLOAD;
        pub_message.payloadlen = strlen(PAYLOAD);
        pub_message.qos = QOS1;
        pub_message.retained = 0;
        delivered_token = 0;

        opts.context = &message;

        MQTTAsync_sendMessage((MQTTAsync)context, TOPIC_OUT, &pub_message, &opts);
    } else {
        MQTTAsync_freeMessage(&message);
        MQTTAsync_free(topic_name);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Any guide to help me debug this is appreciated.

Comment: Anything in the broker logs at the time?

Comment: @hardillb the logs seem normal with just connection instantiation/close events